# jquery effects with asp.net login button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, authentication

Right now I am using an asp.net image button for my login button. I also set masterpage variables during this login process which I display on the front-end using <%= somevariablename %>

The problem I am having is I can't do any nice effects for login validation. All I have is a literal that is hidden and gets displayed on validation error. If I use jquery ajax to fire off the login I can't set the masterpage variables because the method is static...

Anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: Use the standard ASP.NET validation controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-did the login using jquery (no server controls). I changed the way I handled he back-end by storing variables in a session rather than in masterpage properties

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the standard [ASP.NET login controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx). You can style it up to hearts content with css.

> ASP.NET provides robust login (authentication) functionality for
>   ASP.NET Web applications without requiring programming. The default
>   Visual Studio project templates for Web applications and for Web sites
>   include prebuilt pages that let users register a new account, log in,
>   and change their passwords For information about how to use the
>   built-in login page templates, see [Walkthrough: Creating an ASP.NET Web Site with Basic User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Bassistance jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), it's highly customizable and works fine.